# Vector position question

Tags: vectors

I have a set of questions I am struggling to comprehend.

The question is:

> Points A, B, C and D are defined by position vectors a, b, c and d respectively. If $\overrightarrow{AB}$ + $\overrightarrow{CD}$ = $0$.

a) Express d in terms of a, b and c.

> $d=a-b+c$

b) Show that AC and BD bisect each other.

Now here is where I'm struggling.
I recognise:

> $$\overrightarrow{AC}=c-a$$ 
>   $$\overrightarrow{BD}=d-b$$

and  that

> $$\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{-CD}$$

but I can't figure out how to get them into a reasonable format to make the proof that they bisect each other. I'm assuming you use something like

> $$\overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{AC} * \alpha = \overrightarrow{OB} + \overrightarrow{BD} * \beta $$

But it doesn't seem to work like this.

Edit:

I think it could also be done by showing that

> $$\overrightarrow{OA} + 1/2* \overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{OB} + 1/2* \overrightarrow{BD}$$ and substituting in equivalent things like $$d=a-b+c$$ to solve it?

Comment: No, for a) you have the signs wrong. You should have $\vec b-\vec a$. Can you show that $\vec a+\vec c = \vec b + \vec d$? How does this show that the appropriate line segments bisect one another? (Hint: What's the vector to the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$?)

Comment: Do you mean $$ d = a -b + c$$ is not correct?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: If you use $$\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD} = 0$$ and substitute in the vectors you get $$b-a + d-c = 0$$ which when solved for d is $$ d= a-b+c$$

Comment: Oh, darn, my apologies. You're totally right. So what I asked you follows immediately. Why does that show the midpoints of the two line segments are the same?

Comment: Ah I see so if I have $$\overrightarrow{OA} + 1/2*\overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{OB} + 1/2*\overrightarrow{BD}$$ then I can take turn that into $$ a+1/2(c-a)=b+1/2(d-b)$$ which if I take the RHS and substitute in the $$d = a-b+c$$ I get $$b+1/2(a-2b+c)$$ which simplifies to $$a+1/2(c-a)$$ which is the same as the left hand side.